# How to remove pop-up option in printing

Tags: javascript, css, printing, textarea, editor

I want to remove pop-up option from this script while printing the content of textarea so the print page will be in same page of the textarea because i added css so the printed page wont have link or the date "@page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }" but when it pop-up in seperate page it shows link and date

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
<!-- script print button -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function printTextArea() {
 
        childWindow = window.open('','childWindow','location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
        childWindow.document.open();
        childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body dir="rtl">');
        childWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value.replace(/\n/gi,'<br/>'));
        childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        childWindow.print();
        childWindow.document.close();
        childWindow.close();
      }
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
@page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
textarea {
direction: rtl; 
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #00acee;
 resize: none;
}
input[type=button] {
    background-color: #00acee;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <TEXTAREA name="thetext" rows="20" cols="80"id="targetTextArea" placeholder="قم بنسخ و لصق الطلب لملأه و التعديل عليه و طباعته بالزر أسفله ......"></TEXTAREA>
   </p>
   <!-- print button -->
  <center> <input type="button" onclick="printTextArea()" value="طباعة"/></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add a plunker to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When you click on the button in the buttom the text in textarea get printed , but the problem it printed in a pop-up seperate page instead of getting printed in the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are opening a new Window inside `printTextArea()`.

> When opening a window with the window.open() method, you can use this property from the destination window to return details of the source (parent) window.
>   You can read more about it here at w3schools. [W3School Window Opener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)

```
      function printTextArea() {

        childWindow = window.open('','childWindow','location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
        childWindow.document.open();
        childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body dir="rtl">');
        childWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value.replace(/\n/gi,'<br/>'));
        childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        childWindow.print();
        childWindow.document.close();
        childWindow.close();
      }
```

In stead of opening the new window, you should be selecting your textarea by id and updating it's html using `.innerHTML`. Ex:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

Comment: I have just start coding i'm not that good so please what should i do exactly

Comment: @HAMID, you should do this: document.getElementById('targetTextArea').innerHTML = "Your new value Or HTML"; Your print page can have the innerHTML value from whereever you are getting it (i am thinking it's the textarea in this scenario)